# Change variable value only inside function

Tags: php

I have this code in PHP:

```
class PhpClass {
    private static $name   = 'Test name';
    private static $access = 'Test access';

    public static function checkData($param=NULL) {
        if ( $param ) {
            self::$name   = $param['name'];
            self::$access = $param['access'];
        }

        //Rest of the function
    }
}
```

So, basically what I need is to keep the var `$name` and `$access` to always have the default value everytime I call the function `checkData()`, but only change it's value within that function when passing params.

For example, if call the function like this:

```
function functionToCheckData() {
    $class = new PhpClass();

    $param = [
        'name' => 'Another name',
        'access' => 'Another access'
    ];

    $class->checkData($param); //$name and $access should be "another name" and "another access"
    $class->checkData(); //$name and $access should be "test name" and "test access"
}
```

Everytime I call the function `checkData()` I want the variables to have the default value. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `static` right here. Read about static [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

What you need to do:

```
class PhpClass {
    private $name   = 'Test name';
    private $access = 'Test access';

    public static function checkData($param=NULL) {
        if ( $param ) {
            $this->name   = $param['name'];
            $this->access = $param['access'];
        } else {
            $this->name   = 'Test name';
            $this->access = 'Test access';
        }

        //Rest of the function
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns this error: `Using $this when not in object context`. Also, is it necessary to use the `else` part? It seems redundant to redeclare a value that is already the default value. This is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I've just tested it, it works fine. Make sure you copied it right. You have to tell it what to use if `$param` is not set. If you want you changes to be temporary, then declare `$name` and `$access` as local variables in `checkData`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same object. so it will over-write it.

Try this:

```
<?php
   class PhpClass {
    private $name   = 'Test name';
    private $access = 'Test access';

    public  function checkData($param=NULL) {
        if ( $param ) {
            $this->name   = $param['name'];
            $this->access = $param['access'];
        } 
        echo $this->name."<br>";
        //Rest of the function
    }
}
function functionToCheckData() {
    $class = new PhpClass();

    $param = [
        'name' => 'Another name',
        'access' => 'Another access'
    ];

    $class->checkData($param); //$name and $access should be "another name" and "another access"
     $class1 = new PhpClass();
    $class1->checkData(); //$name and $access should be "test name" and "test access"
}
functionToCheckData();
```